# QueryExpression Phonecall to Contact

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've been stuck on this for a bit. Here's the scope of what I'm trying to do:

Retrieve phonecall records while bringing in contact information within the "to" field.

After much research, I have boiled down the code to below. I'm not too sure if I'm doing linked entities right - but can't determine how to do a nested join like I need to as I need to somehow get to the activitypointer -> activityparty -> contact...I just don't know where I"m going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.Samples;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.Samples;

QueryExpression qExpression = new QueryExpression("phonecall")
{
    ColumnSet = cs,
    LinkEntities = 
    {

        new LinkEntity()
        {
            EntityAlias = "ap",
            LinkFromEntityName= "phonecall",
            LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
            LinkToEntityName = "activitypointer",
            LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
            JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner
        },
        new LinkEntity()
        {
            EntityAlias = "app",
            LinkFromEntityName= "activitypointer",
            LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
            LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
            LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
            JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
            LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression
             {
                 Conditions = 
                 {
                     new ConditionExpression("ParticipationTypeMask", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2),                          
                 }
             }
        },
        new LinkEntity()
        {
            EntityAlias = "con",
            Columns = new ColumnSet("fullname","contactid"),
            JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
            LinkFromEntityName = "activityparty",
            LinkFromAttributeName = "partyid",
            LinkToEntityName = "contact",
            LinkToAttributeName = "contactid"
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I answered my own question, giving some inspiration. I had to nest the link within a link.

This is what works now

```
QueryExpression qExpression = new QueryExpression("phonecall")
        {
            ColumnSet = cs,
            LinkEntities = 
            {                   
                new LinkEntity()
                {
                    EntityAlias = "app",
                    LinkFromEntityName= "phonecall",
                    LinkFromAttributeName = "activityid",
                    LinkToEntityName = "activityparty",
                    LinkToAttributeName = "activityid",
                    JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
                    LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression
                     {
                         Conditions = 
                         {
                             new ConditionExpression("participationtypemask", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2),                          
                         }
                     },
                     LinkEntities = 
                     {                             
                        new LinkEntity()
                        {
                            EntityAlias = "con",
                            Columns = new ColumnSet("fullname","contactid"),
                            JoinOperator = JoinOperator.Inner,
                            LinkFromEntityName = "activityparty",
                            LinkFromAttributeName = "partyid",
                            LinkToEntityName = "contact",
                            LinkToAttributeName = "contactid"
                        }
                     }
                },
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [DLaB.Xrm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DLaB.Xrm.2016/), you could re-write this like this:

```cs
var qe = QueryExpressionFactory.Create(cs, "phonecall");
var activityParty = qe.AddLink("activityparty", "activityid");
activityParty.WhereEqual("participationtypemask", 2);
activityParty.AddLink("contact", "partyid", "contactid")
             .AddColumns("fullname","contactid");
```

Having a lot less code to look at tends to make it easier to Grok IMHO.

This is how I would read teach line of my 5 lines listed:

1. I'm doing a Query against the Phone Call Entity
2. Joining to the Activity Party on the activity Id (same key for both, no need to duplicate)
3. Where the activityParty's ParticipationTypeMask == 2
4. And joining from that to the Contact on ActivityParty.PartyId == Contact.ContactId
5. Including the name and Id of the contact.